# Using git-svn without "trunk" sub-directory

Tags: git, svn, directory, git-svn, trunk

I'm using git-svn to checkout a standard SVN repository such as this one:

```
http://example.com/
    - trunk
    - branches
    - tags
```

with this command:

```
git svn clone -s http://example.com/
```

The problem is that git-svn is creating a "trunk" sub-directory in the target folder. Instead of having this kind of directory structure:

```
c:\www\example
```

I'm having this:

```
c:\www\example\trunk
```

So how to prevent git-svn from putting everything in this trunk folder, while still using the standard SVN layout? Basically, I would want "c:\www\example" to contain whatever I'm currently working on, whether it's the trunk, a branch or a tag. On the other hand, I also need git-svn to correctly map the git branches and tags to the correct SVN folders. Can this be done with git-svn or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe you should run: "git svn clone -s http://example.com/ ." (dot at the end tells git-svn to clone into the current directory, see "git svn --help" for more information).

Comment: @DmitryPavlenko, yes that was it. Feel free to post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should run:

```
git svn clone -s http://example.com/ .
```

(dot at the end tells git-svn to clone into the current directory, see `git svn --help` for more information).